# Which header file should I include for using _swprintf_s()?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010

When I used **_swprintf()**, it said it might be unsafe and I should use _swprintf_s instead.

But when I used **_swprintf_s()**, it said

> error C3861: '_swprintf_s': identifier
>   not found

Which header am I missing? I

Answer (score 8):

It is swprintf() and swprintf_s().  No leading underscore.